# window.print Duplicate content after pagination

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I used the printJs plugin to call what is needed for `window.print` printing

Because there is a lot of content, the browser has automatically paginated.

But I found that after the second page, all pages have more content than the previous page.

The second page has the content of the first page, and the third page has the content of the first two pages,like the picture above.

I want to know what caused this problem, plugin or browser printing, or my code?
[image: preview]

```
/* print */
Print.onclick = function () {
    printJS({
        printable: "printmain",
        type: "html",
        css: '/css/printjs.css',
        scanStyles: false
    });
};
```